# Radius of convergence of a power series and the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem.

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, power-series

I am trying to find the radius of convergence of the series
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{k^k+2}{k!}z^k.
$$
I know the radius of convergence of such a series is given by the Cauchy-Hadamard theorem, which states that for the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty a_kz^k$ the radius of convergence R is given by
$$
\frac{1}{R}=\limsup_{k\to\infty}(|a_k|)^{\frac{1}{k}}.
$$
Thus, in my case, the $\limsup$ to compute is
$$
\limsup_{k\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{k^k+2}{k!}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{k}},
$$
but I cannot find a way to compute it.

Comment: I'd forget the $2$.

Comment: Okay, so I'd be left with $\limsup_{k\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{k^k}{k!}\bigg)^{\frac{1}{k}}=\limsup_{k\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{k}{(k!)^{\frac{1}{k}}}\bigg)$, should this be obvious? I don't see it.

Comment: If you know Stirling's formula it is obvious; I'd suggest using the ratio test rather than the root test though.

Comment: +10 to @AnginaSeng's comment